# Why does a margin animation on one div apply to every other div aswell?

Tags: html, css

so basically i have a keyframe class set to "slide" but when i run the sliding animation on one div, every other div in the html page moves with it (in my case there is a total of 3 divs) i want only 1 div (the square) to move up and rotate, but the slide animation makes everything go up but the rotation only applies to the div i set it to.
source code here:

```css
.Square1{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color: white;


    animation: spin 10s linear infinite, slide 10s linear infinite;

    margin: 100px;
    padding: 0;
}


/*Spin Animation*/

@keyframes spin{
    100%{transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@keyframes slide {
    from { margin-top: 0px;}
    to { margin-top: -200px;}   
   }

CSS Body Main: body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: black;
}

.GameButton1:hover{
font-size:130px;
}

.GameButton1:hover img{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    
}
.GameButton1{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    text-align:right;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    font-size:50px;
    transition:1s;
    
}

.GameButton1 img{
    position:relative;
    text-align:right;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    transition:1s;
}



.Info{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    font-size:50px;
    transition:1s;
}

.Info img{
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    transition:1s;
}

.Info:hover{
    font-size:150px;
    }
    
.Info:hover img{
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Main Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MenuConfig.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="SquareRotation.css">

    <div class="GameButton1"></div>
    <div class="GameButtonSideImage"></div>

    <div class="Info"></div>

    <div class="Square1"></div>
    <div class="Square2"></div>
    <div class="Square3"></div>
    <div class="Square4"></div>
    <div class="Square5"></div>
    <div class="Square6"></div>
    <div class="Square7"></div>

    <a class="Info" href="Options/Info/Info.html"><img src="Options/PhotosLibraryMenu/Info.png" width="50px" height="50px">Info</a>
    <a class="GameButton1" href="Options/Games/Game.html"><img class="GameButtonSideImage" src="Options/PhotosLibraryMenu/PlayButtonUsing.png" width="50px" height="50px">Games</a>

    <audio src="Audio/ButtonHover.mp3" class="Enter"></audio>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yousoumar i dont quite understand could you get into more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin applied to the first square is **not** being applied to the other squares.

However, the squares are positioned one after the other and so as you make the margin of the first one less, the others all move up.

There seems no reason to have two separate sets of keyframes in this instance so this snippet combines the two. It does not alter the margin of the first square but translates it in the Y direction. Transforms do not alter the positioning within the DOM so the other squares are not affected.

```css
.Square1 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  animation: spinslide 10s linear infinite;
  margin: 100px;
  padding: 0;
}


/*Spin and Rotate Animation*/

@keyframes spinslide {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-200px) rotate(360deg);
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.GameButton1:hover {
  font-size: 130px;
}

.GameButton1:hover img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.GameButton1 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.GameButton1 img {
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.Info {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.Info img {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.Info:hover {
  font-size: 150px;
}

.Info:hover img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Main Menu</title>
</head>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="MenuConfig.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="SquareRotation.css">

  <div class="GameButton1"></div>
  <div class="GameButtonSideImage"></div>

  <div class="Info"></div>

  <div class="Square1"></div>
  <div class="Square2"></div>
  <div class="Square3"></div>
  <div class="Square4"></div>
  <div class="Square5"></div>
  <div class="Square6"></div>
  <div class="Square7"></div>

  <a class="Info" href="Options/Info/Info.html"><img src="Options/PhotosLibraryMenu/Info.png" width="50px" height="50px">Info</a>
  <a class="GameButton1" href="Options/Games/Game.html"><img class="GameButtonSideImage" src="Options/PhotosLibraryMenu/PlayButtonUsing.png" width="50px" height="50px">Games</a>

  <audio src="Audio/ButtonHover.mp3" class="Enter"></audio>



</body>

</html>
```

While this stops the other elements moving, the effect of the animation seems a bit jerky. You perhaps need to look at introducing forwards to the animation and reversing it or something? I can't tell from the info given exactly what effect you want.

Comment: thanks for the explination,  but there seems to be a mistake in your code. now the square is rotating in a circular motion, we want it to go up and rotate the square itself as it goes.

Comment: also by squares i meant the menu buttons. atm there is only one square

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by 'only one square'? I just used the HTML given. I don't know what else you want or might be there. Please add them to the question.

Comment: yeah sorry about that. so the rest of the square divs just exist. but Square1 is being used rn to test this thing with. the problem here is that the square is moving itself along with the gamebuttons

Comment: I got the order of the transforms the wrong way round. Now corrected.